# Jackson @JsonIgnoreProperties - combining rules

Tags: java, json, jackson

I want to be able to ignore unknown properties as well as a specific field.  I know how to do it in separate annotations:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"origin" })
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
```

Obviously I can't have two annotations.  Is it possible to combine this?

Comment: Is `origin` the name of an instance field? If yes you can just `@JsonIgnore` that field in addition to ignoring unknown properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to do it.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
abstract class someclass{
@JsonCreator
someclass(
@JsonProperty("type") String type,@JsonProperty("origin") Origin origin) {}
}
```